# Php filename doesn't display after submitting the form

Tags: php, html

I'd like to open a file from browser, to be later uploaded to ftp. My code works on localhost, but when I test it on my domain, it writes "There's no file selected", but right after selecting the file, without submitting the form it displays that I've selected my file. I could really use some help. I just want to print the name of the selected file after submitting the form. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
      <input type="submit" name="upl" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upl'])){
        echo "Name: ".$_FILE['file']['name'];
     }
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it works locally but not on the hosted site, is it possible the host site disallows file uploads in their php conf?

Comment: first of all make your form with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: ^^ good point no way this should be working locally with out that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small typo there.

`$_FILES` not `$_FILE`

Comment: Also check [this article](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links) regarding using PHP_SELF

Comment: Thanks man my fault. Didn't notice. Sorry for bothering you with such questions. Wait 10 mins and get my accept :D

Comment: Thank you, after reading that, I should really stop using them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the input type file you have to mansion **enctype="multipart/form-data"**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="submit" name="upl" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upl'])){
        echo "Name: ".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     }
  ?>
```